# IDENTITY vs BIGINT regarding _ROWID_

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

My understanding is that the only difference between
`CREATE TABLE T(ID IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY);`
and
`CREATE TABLE T(ID BIGINT IDENTITY);`
is that the latter is more efficient since the `ID` column is the row id and as such corresponds the `_ROWID_` pseudo-column.

Also, if I do
`CREATE TABLE T(ID IDENTITY);`
then `ID` doesn't correspond to `_ROWID_` and it isn't even a primary key at all.

Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: I suspect not.  Create a table using the second method.  Add two records then delete the first one.  Select the id field and _rowid_ values and see if they are still the same.  Next, create another table with a foreign key reference to the first one.  See if the database lets you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested I did some tests.
It turns out that all the three statements appear to be equivalent.
`ID` is always the primary key and corresponds to the `_ROWID_` column.

After all, I went with a fourth variant:
`CREATE TABLE T(ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, CONSTRAINT KEY_NAME PRIMARY KEY (ID));`
This has the advantage that the primary key's name can be specified.
In the other cases the name was automatically generated, something along the lines of `CONSTRAINT_0`.
All of this with H2 1.4.190.